# Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not send query: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Tags: spring, mariadb

I am getting    "Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not send query: Software caused connection abort: socket write error" while persisting large files as LONGBLOB in MariaDB. We are using Spring with EclipseLink on MariaDB 5.5. 
All files of size less than roughly 300KB are persisted but more than that results in this error.

We are using MariaDB for the first time in the organization and I have no idea which DB variables should  be set to adequate values so that transactions which persist large files and longer than normal will not  result in this error.

Any quick help on this is much appreciated. I am looking for a solution on my side and  if I find a solution will update this post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by increasing the values set to server system variables below:

max_allowed_packet = 500M

net_read_timeout=900

net_write_timeout=900

connect_timeout=900

Out of the above the main culprit was the first one which is "max_allowed_packet". For more details please refer https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/optimization-and-tuning/system-variables/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet